# Swift Realm "Group By" like android room database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using realm in my project and register here category name

I want to list the same categories as one group and write the group numbers next to this list.

This is my Realm database:

```
import RealmSwift

class CatList: Object {
    @objc dynamic var catname: String = ""
}
```

I can list data with this code:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var Items: Results<CatList>?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Items = realm.objects(CatList.self)
}
```

Let's say there are 5 categories in the database

> Green
>
> Yellow
>
> Red
>
> Yellow
>
> Green

i have to list the same categories once and print the total number next to it.

So it should be like this;

```
Green 2
```

```
---------
```

```
Yellow 2
```

```
---------
```

```
Red 1
```

Note: To help, I can do this on android Room as follows.

`@Query("Select id, catname, COUNT(catname) AS total FROM catlist GROUP BY catname ORDER BY total DESC")`

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm results are homogeneous; they will contain only one type of data.

Therefore a Realm query will only return one type of object so you can't directly extract both the category name and count at the same time via a Realm query*

But the solution is pretty straightforward; capture a unique list of categories, iterate over them and output the count of each.

```
let results = realm.objects(CatList.self).distinct(by: ["catname"])
for category in results {
    let cat = category.catname
    let count = realm.objects(CatList.self).where { $0.catname == cat}.count
    print("category: \(cat) has a count of \(count)")
}
```

A couple of notes: At this time, it's a good idea to move on to the more modern Realm implementation using [@Persisted](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/object-models/#persisted-property-attributes)

```
class CatList: Object {
    @Persisted var catname = ""
}
```

Also - for readability, since the object isn't a list, it's a single object, CatList could probably be better named Category.

*The above is a Realm and memory friendly solution handling the data in a [lazy-loading](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-database/#live-object) fashion. That being said, a one-liner could likely be achieved with Swift High Order functions - however, that's generally not recommended if the dataset is large or of unknown size.